# Timeout when pulling any image in docker (local issue: gateway.docker.internal)

Tags: macos, docker

**[Problem]**

I am getting the following error using any pull command (`docker pull bash:latest`):

`Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup gateway.docker.internal on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp 192.168.65.3:38813->192.168.65.1:53: i/o timeout`

Started happening randomly yesterday. Cannot give any more useful info than this, because I don't have any.

**[Solutions I have tried]**

1. I have added the host `127.0.0.1` for `gateway.docker.internal` and for `host.docker.internal` in `/etc/hosts`/.
2. I have reinstalled the docker.
3. I have used different dns servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). Both in `/etc/resolv.conf` and by setting them in the Docker GUI settings.
4. I have even reinstalled the MacOS (via command + R).

Nothing is fixing this issue. Would be really good to get an input from someone. I have wasted two days on this, and no progress.

**[Note]**

The only thing that gives me a different error, is when I use the subnet in GUI docker that is copied from `docker network inspect bridge`. If I do so, I get the connection refused error postfix instead of the time out.

I really don't know much about networks, please do let me know if there are any other details you might be interested in.

Comment: What command are you running to get that error?  When you say “used 127.0.0.1 for gateway.docker.internal”, what did you actually do?  (That IP address is probably wrong for that host name, but that may not be your problem.)

Comment: (1) I use: `docker pull bash:latest` (2) `sudo vim /etc/hosts` and then added those two there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

```
$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup gateway.docker.internal on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp 192.168.65.3:58231->192.168.65.1:53: i/o timeout.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

In my case I had to stop the company Antivirus/firewall agent. It started working afterwards.